# Configuring multiple relationships between several unit types in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

I have several tables in MYSQL DB with units I have to relate to each other, e.g.:

- products
- product categories
- experiments
- experiment categories
- downloads
- articles

Each pair should have relationship.

As the number of types was gradually incrementing from just products and categories, I started with simple xref tables with two-id keys / foreign keys, e.g. **product_id | category_id**.

Now, with all the above-mentioned at hands, I'm thinking it could've been done with one relationship table for all types, something like:

```
table_name1 | item_id1 | table_name2 | item_id2
```

Problem is, I don't see how to configure the foreign keys so that the data integrity is kept by the DB itself and (oh, well) also even how to build queries from this.

What strategies at DB level can be used to keep graph structures like this in MYSQL?

If I stick with MYSQL, am I bound to have single xref for each relationship or is there some clever way to have such graph stored with data integrity imposed?

Or should I think of using other databases? If so, which ones would work good with nodejs?

Thanks in advance )

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, or suboptimal, with your current arrangement

Comment: In all relational databases the foreign key relationships are defined in DDL (create / alter / drop) and are part of the db structure. Your proposed solution would push this information into the data of a table, which is not supported by any of the relational databases.

Comment: @Strawberry, it starts looking rather suboptimal whenever I have to add new relationship or new entity. At this point, I would need 15 xref tables and call 15 queries to fetch all related entities for a single item. If we add another entity type, it's gonna be 21 and so on. Seeing a common pattern in setting relationships, I can't stop thinking about normalizing them. :)

Comment: @Shadow yep, that's a problem. So how do I do it correctly within relational database?

Comment: With respect, you may be overthinking / overgeneralizing. It's just fine to design an E-R model where the relationship structure match the real-world system you are modeling. SQL's foreign key constraint system is, as you know, set up to handle that.  Don't needlessly create entities (like your generalized relationship table proposal). But, do think about your taxonomies (categories) and how you'll use them in future. WordPress handles taxonomies well. https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Taxonomy

Comment: @O.Jones, thank you :) So do I understand it right that you suggest to keep building xref tables for each one of the relationships?

Comment: Exactly. When you have a meaningful many-to-many relationship in your E-R model, implement it with a relationship table. If it's a one to many relationship, don't use a relationship table, just a foreign key. For what it's worth, the original formulation of Occam's Razor was "do not needlessly multiply entities." It's still specific and good advice 700 years later.

Comment: @O.Jones: thank you for the link to WordPress taxonomy structure, it is definitely an interesting approach, something along the lines of what I was trying to build. Will check out whether I can use it in my case.